# how to check the position of my control in android

Tags: android, position, scroll

I want to check if my control is at the top and under the action bar while scrolling.

That control is at the end of my view and its size is `screenSize - actionbarsize - notificationBarsize`. Actually it is a listView and I want it to scroll only when control is at top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

From the description you have provided it seems https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel would solve your problem

Comment: I'll see this, but if you want example I want something like Google+ app profile page. When we scroll content it doesn't scroll till its tab reaches on top.